# Did Pablo Picasso state "The hidden harmony is better than the obvious"?

Tags: quotes

I came across this quotation on page 145 of [*National Geographic Stunning Photographs*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20697512-national-geographic-stunning-photographs). Google retrieved at least 100 results for it. [Gunnar Nordstrom Gallery](http://www.gunnarnordstrom.com/dynamic/exhibit_artist.asp?ArtistID=129&ExhibitID=206)

> Two particular works to be exhibited share historical similarities as well as juxtaposed iconography by two different Spanish artists. The first by Pablo Picasso is from 1922 and is a lovely dry point etching "Femme au Miroir" or "Woman looking onto a Mirror". Sitting nude, but reserved (much different than later works by Picasso also on display) a woman holds a mirror and gazes into it daydreaming of beauty, fashion and the future. Picasso said, "**The hidden harmony is better than the obvious**" as evident in this jewel of a print.

But this S.E. user couldn't find the primary source.

> *This* may be a case where challenging the authenticity of the statement would have been appropriate. All sources I find for this post date publication in a 'quote book' in 2001, and the original can be linked to [Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus#Philosophy) ***"a hidden harmony is better than an apparent one."*** quite a while before Picasso. – [justCal](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/16951/justcal)

Did Picasso actually say this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably some [artistic license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license) in the NatGeo book in making that attribution.

What is certain is that the (1922) painting being discussed right before belongs to Picasso's [classical period](https://www.jstor.org/stable/875583). Another (more) notable painting of his from this era is the [Pipes of Pan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pipes_of_Pan_(painting)), with a more obvious classical Greek theme.

Furthermore Picasso was (somewhat superficially) aware of the philosophies of classical Greece. In a biography that quotes/interviews eyewitnesses (*Picasso: Creator and Destroyer* by Arianna Stassinopoulos Huffington, p. 340), Picasso is attributed to have said at one point (to [Javier Vilató](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javier_Vilat%C3%B3))

> I prefer Heraclitus to Plato.

Which may explain why someone would turn that kind of preference into a story of Picasso quoting/restating something that Heraclitus said.

(Now Huffington's work, including this book, has been questioned [in terms of plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arianna_Huffington#Claims_of_plagiarism), but ironically I couldn't find this bit about Picasso liking Heraclitus mentioned elsewhere... Someone may want to check [Lydia Gasman](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/02/06/arts/06gasman.html)'s thesis, as she also interviewed relatives of Picasso, but this work is not easily available.)

---

(To add to the confusion, Picasso has a much more famous [1932 painting "Girl Before a Mirror"](https://books.google.com/books?id=PVHodcMzpgQC)
from his suprarealist period, but that's clearly not what's being discussed--the 1922 etching [exists as well](https://www.cityartsmagazine.com/issues-eastside-2010-04-curators-eye-0/), and it's not supra-realist.)